# E: Unable to locate package livestreamer

Tags: 20.04

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package livestreamer

Is the error I receive when trying to install livestreamer on ubuntu 20.04

The command I execute : `sudo apt-get install livestreamer`

Comment: That package isn't available for focal/20.04 https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=livestreamer&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the directions on their site aren't correct, at least for 20.04. The software is not, in fact, in the repositories for 20.04.

That's okay. Follow these directions:

```
python3 --version
```

That will let you know if Python is installed. It probably is.

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Let it run its course.

```
sudo pip3 install livestreamer
```

Then, follow their documentation for use [here](https://docs.livestreamer.io/).

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04.